# Multer successfully uploads images to folder but they cannot be displayed - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript

I am using multer to upload images .On upload, images are nicely posted to uploads folder but on trying to use them they cant show, could somebody tell me where have gone wrong.

I have tried using express.static but still it could not work. My uploads folder is situated in public folder  "/client/public/uploads"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.